# Can't use "display: table" in Outlook after using "display: none" on table

Tags: css, outlook

Consider the below HTML email. It has a banner at the top which is hidden via the CSS rule `table {display: none !important;}`. It is then shown again via the more specific CSS rule `body table {display: table !important;}`. This is working as expected in all browsers, including Internet Explorer 11. However, in Outlook, the second CSS rule does not seem to have any effect. Strangely, just the content is hidden in Outlook rather than the whole table. But the content is not shown again using the second rule.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=us-ascii" />
    <style>
      table {
        display: none !important;
      }
    </style>
    <style>
      body table {
        display: table !important;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" style="cellpadding: 0;border: 0;cellspacing: 0;display: table;width: 100%;table-layout: fixed;border-collapse: seperate;float: none;" align="left">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td valign="middle" width="1px" bgcolor="#A6A6A6" cellpadding="7px 2px 7px 2px" style="padding: 7px 2px 7px 2px;background-color: #a6a6a6;valign: middle;"></td>
          <td valign="middle" width="100%" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" cellpadding="7px 5px 7px 15px" color="#212121" style="width: 100%;background-color: #eaeaea;padding: 7px 5px 7px 15px;font-family: wf_segoe-ui_normal, Segoe UI, Segoe WP, Tahoma, Arial,sans-serif;font-size: 12px;font-weight: normal;color: #212121;text-align: left;word-wrap: break-word;">
            <div>This table should be visible.</div>
          </td>
          <td valign="middle" align="left" width="75px" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" cellpadding="7px 5px 7px 5px" color="#212121" style="width: 75px;background-color: #eaeaea;padding: 7px 5px 7px 5px;font-family: wf_segoe-ui_normal, Segoe UI, Segoe WP, Tahoma, Arial,sans-serif;font-size: 12px;font-weight: normal;color: #212121;text-align: left;word-wrap: break-word;align: left;"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <div>This is a test</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Removing `!important` from either or both rules has no effect. How can I override the initial `display: none` and make the banner visible again?

For context if it helps, these banners are inserted by Office 365 for things like warning users when a message looks like phishing. One issue is that phishing messages can hide these banners with a few lines of CSS. I am trying to write CSS to append to the end of the message which will make the banner visible again. This approach works in OWA and Outlook for iOS, but not Outlook for Windows.

The issue is also explained in [this tweet](https://twitter.com/ldionmarcil/status/1384987686113583107).

Comment: I suggest to build content using conditional operators. That is more readable for emails and easy to implement.

Comment: @T.kowshikYedida I have no control over the content, it is inserted by Office 365. The issue here is that the email can contain a `<style>`  tag which hides the table, and a subsequent `<style>` tag is not able to show it again. Here is a tweet about this issue if it gives more context: https://twitter.com/ldionmarcil/status/1384987686113583107

Comment: Ok. The tweet says it has to be on the gateway side but not from user. Are you a network administrator trying to disable this message? Even then, it is not advised to remove those messages unless you are into phishing.

Comment: I am a security engineer trying to harden my system. I turned the banner on, it is inserted by the gateway (Office 365). When a phishing email arrives, it can have CSS from the attacker (user) which hides the banner. I am trying to create a mailflow rule which will add CSS to show the banner again in case an attacker's email hides it.

Comment: now I got the context. Can you try all:initial and then display:table?

Comment: That didn't seem to make a difference. It wouldn't be a good approach anyway, as it would alter the appearance of emails which use CSS for valid reasons.

Comment: Yes you are right that it will override all the styles. That's what I wanted to check if the changes are reflecting at all. I don't have exposure to gateway email configuration. How is the style added to mail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt if this works in outlook display.
display: table !important;

if you just keep this line and remove does it work.
Anyway you are already using table html.
so try using

```
display: block !important;
```

instead of

display: table !important;

i think table was for divs to display as table. but outlook does not support it

Comment: I thought I had tried `display: block`. I just tried again and it works, but only if the `<style>` tag is located in the `<head>` section. So the root issue here seems to be that Outlook doesn't support `display: table` on tables, as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You are using both, the `style` element (`<style>`) and inline style (`style="..."`)

So you need to know that there could be a conflict...
As far as I know, Outlook works better with inline styles,

so try to choose only this one and work with it, if this is an option.
Otherwise you will need to update both.

Comment: I have no control of the HTML between `<table` and `</table>`, it is inserted automatically by Office 365. An attacker is then able to hide the table by inserting the first `<style>`  tag in an email. There should be no "conflict" as CSS is designed to have multiple competing rules added by many different means, and the more specific rule wins and is applied. The second `<style>` tag is what is being inserted by me, and since it is more specific, it should be showing the table again.

Comment: @jdgregson Have you tried other values? Like `display: initial;`?
And the issue here is not that the second rule is more specific, it's just more recent, and it should technically overwrite the previous one.

Another test you can do is changing the order of these 2 rules, and see how Outlook behaves...

Comment: I have tried a few different values, including `display: initial;`, but none of them seemed to work either. Putting the `display: table !important` rule first also doesn't make a difference. While the order of rules does play a role in deciding which rules apply, ["Specificity is the means by which browsers decide which CSS property values are the most relevant to an element and, therefore, will be applied"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). Here is a quick demonstration: https://jsfiddle.net/rkwb7t92/

Answer (score 0):

> When using CSS in email it is preferable to use Inline CSS.
> Avoid embedded and external CSS in HTML emails.
> Because browser-based email applications, such as Gmail, strip out `<head>` > and `<body>` tags by default, always use inline CSS over embedded CSS.

[General CSS tips and troubleshooting](https://mailchimp.com/help/css-in-html-email/#General_CSS_tips_and_troubleshooting)

[CSS in HTML emails](https://content.myemma.com/blog/css-in-html-emails-what-you-need-to-know-to-get-started)

Comment: Thanks for the information. I don't have the option to use inline CSS here. First of all, the element I am trying to modify with CSS has already been created so I am unable to modify it with inline CSS. Second, this is about Outlook, where `<style>` tags work just fine. Third, I can't ask attackers to use inline CSS, so I have to counter their `<style>` tag with another `<style>` tag.